# unable to run codeception in virtual machine -Mink could not be found and loaded

Tags: php, virtual-machine, acceptance-testing, mink, codeception

I installed a vm ubuntu guest OS.

My app is running from the browser in my host OS at the url

http://abc.localhost:8888

I type 
php codecept.phar run in the guest OS terminal.

I get the following error:

```
[Codeception\Exception\Configuration]  
  Mink could not be found and loaded
```

My acceptance.yml says

```
# Codeception Test Suite Configuration

# suite for acceptance tests.
# perform tests in browser using the Selenium-like tools.
# powered by Mink (http://mink.behat.org).
# (tip: that's what your customer will see).
# (tip: test your ajax and javascript by one of Mink drivers).

# RUN `build` COMMAND AFTER ADDING/REMOVING MODULES.

class_name: WebGuy
modules:
    enabled:
        - PhpBrowser
        - WebHelper
        - Mink
    config:
        PhpBrowser:
           url: 'http://abc.localhost:8888'
```

I have tried with and without the 8888 in the acceptance.suite.yml. I get the same error.

Please advise.

Caveat: I have also cross-posted the same ticket in https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/388. Will update this question should I get answer from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. SSH into guest VM.
2. sudo nano /etc/hosts
3. Add in the following `127.0.0.1 abc.localhost`
4. Ensure acceptance.yml is correct.

> ```
> # Codeception Test Suite Configuration
>
> # suite for acceptance tests.
> # perform tests in browser using the Selenium-like tools.
> # powered by Mink (http://mink.behat.org).
> # (tip: that's what your customer will see).
> # (tip: test your ajax and javascript by one of Mink drivers).
>
> # RUN `build` COMMAND AFTER ADDING/REMOVING MODULES.
>
> class_name: WebGuy
> modules:
>     enabled:
>         - PhpBrowser
>         - WebHelper
>     config:
>         PhpBrowser:
>            url: 'http://abc.localhost'
> ```

Then you run the command `php codecept.phar run` inside your guest vm